# Android java.lang.VerifyError with PagerAdapter.getItem

Tags: java, android

I wanna call a map from tab pager adapter .  a pageradapter puts in main fragment. 
when calling getItem() then my application crashes

```
public static class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new FragmentTest();
            break;

        case 1:
            fragment = new FragmentMap(); //here's error!!
            break;

        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

map fragment

```
public class FragmentMap extends Fragment{

Context context;

MapView mapView;
GoogleMap map;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.people_map_fragment_layout, container, false);
// Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
try {
    MapsInitializer.initialize(context);
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    Log.e("Address Map", "Could not initialize google play", e);
}

switch (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity()) )
{
case ConnectionResult.SUCCESS:
  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
  mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
  if(mapView!=null)
  {
  map = mapView.getMap();
  map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
  map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
  CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(43.1, -87.9), 10);
  map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
  }
  break;
case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING: 
  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SERVICE MISSING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  break;
case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED: 
  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "UPDATE REQUIRED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  break;
default: Toast.makeText(getActivity(), GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
return v;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {

super.onResume();
if(mapView!=null)
    mapView.onResume();
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
if(mapView!=null)
mapView.onDestroy();
}
@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
super.onLowMemory();
if(mapView!=null)
mapView.onLowMemory();
}
}
```

But i get always error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError:FragmentMap
at FragmentMain$PagerAdapter.getItem()
```

what is wrong with my code?pls help

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen when I override methods that I'm not supposed to override, in your case, I would check if methods getItemPosition and  getPageTitle are allowed to be overridden or not because, from the FragmentPagerAdapter documentation,  (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html), 
Subclasses only need to implement getItem(int) and getCount() to have a working adapter. The doc also says When using FragmentPagerAdapter the host ViewPager must have a valid ID set, so that would be another thing to verify.